# AVG Downloaded but I cannot run

Tags: antivirus

I downloaded AVG to pc.  I am running Ubuntu 14.04. When I open a terminal window and type `AVGsetup` it comes back saying:

```
Permission denied
```

Comment: Please provide the command you use. "Permission denied" generally means you need to use "sudo" in front of a command and provide the admin password.

Comment: Ubuntu is based on the Debian distribution, so it would be easier to download the AVG .deb file from the official AVG website, instead of the .sh or the .tar.gz file, and then double click the .deb file to open it for installation in the Ubuntu Software Center.

Answer (score 1):

According to the License Agreement on use of AVG AntiVirus Free Edition, the AVG license grants you permission to use AVG AntiVirus Free Edition "solely ... on a single computer". The definition of solely which is "not involving anyone or anything else; only" seems to be restrictive enough that it fully excludes installing AVG on more than one computer. I think that "anything else" would also exclude installing AVG on both OSs of a single computer with a dual boot. I think that the words "anything else" mean that you can install AVG on one operating system for personal use and that's it. Unlike the ClamTk antivirus application from the Ubuntu Software Center, which you can install on as many computers as you like.

### Installation

1. Visit the [Download AVG AntiVirus Free 2015](http://free.avg.com/ww-en/download-free-all-product) website.
2. Under the **AVG AntiVirus Free - for Linux** header download the .deb file for installing AVG AntiVirus in Debian-based systems like Ubuntu.
3. Users of 64-bit Ubuntu should enable [MultiArch](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultiArch) if it isn't already enabled by running the following command in the terminal:

   ```
   sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
   ```
4. Double click the AVG .deb file to open it for installation in the Ubuntu Software Center. This is the easiest way to install AVG AntiVirus in Ubuntu.